# What does the prefix "\c@" mean in build log?

Tags: macros, counters

I just follow the LaTeX tutorial to create the first "Hello World!" `.tex` file, and translate it to PDF file.

Then I go through the `.log` file and see the following,

```
("C:\Program Files\MikTeX\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) (hello_world.aux)
```

I am confused with the statements, like

```
\c@part=\count79
```

Anyone can explain this?

Comment: [Welcome to this LaTeX stackexchange](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/34551). What is "that LaTeX tutorial"? Could you provide a reference or a link? To obtain a `pdf` file from a `tex` one is obtained by "compiling" your source file, and not by "translating" it. Did you get you `pdf` file as expected? Are you looking at your `log` file to debug something, or out of curiosity?

Comment: TeX uses count registers (0-255 normally) to handle counters.  In fact counter "part" is implemented as count register "\c@part".  The statement "\c@part=\count79" copies the value in count register 79 (no idea) into counter "part.".  The @ symbol is used to deter mere mortals from accessing them.

Comment: Thanks all! The LaTeX tutorial is from the link http://www.latex-tutorial.com/tutorials/beginners/lesson-1/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You probably compiled the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello World!
\end{document}
```

which provided the following (partial) `.log`:

```
...
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
...
```

The above output stems from counter definitions within the default `article` document class. More specifically, the following set of commands (just search for `\newcounter` in `article.cls`):

```
...
\newcounter {part}
\newcounter {section}
\newcounter {subsection}[section]
\newcounter {subsubsection}[subsection]
\newcounter {paragraph}[subsubsection]
\newcounter {subparagraph}[paragraph]
...
\newcounter{figure}
...
\newcounter{table}
...
```

Each `\newcounter{<newcntr>}[<oldcntr>]` defines a new counter as a *macro* `\c@<newcntr>` - note the prefix `c@`. Here's the definition of `\newcounter` from the LaTeX kernel:

```
\def\newcounter#1{%
  \expandafter\@ifdefinable \csname c@#1\endcsname
    {\@definecounter{#1}}%
  \@ifnextchar[{\@newctr{#1}}{}}
```

At first it checks whether a macro `\c@<newcntr>` already exists, and then defines it via `\@definecounter{<newcntr>}`.

```
\def\@definecounter#1{\expandafter\newcount\csname c@#1\endcsname
  ...}
```

`\@definecounter` issues the TeX primitive `\newcount` to create the actual count register that `\c@<newcntr>` points to.

The use of the `c@` prefix is purely a conventional choice. In a similar manner, counter prefixes have a `p@` macro prefix, while references (or `\label`s) in the LaTeX kernel have an `r@` prefix. It attempts to avoid end-users from messing around with the counters, yet still allow them to create their own similarly-named macros. That is, making the following work without problem:

```
\newcounter{something}% <------- Creates \c@something
\newcommand{\something}{..}% <-- Creates \something
```

If the `c@` prefix wasn't inserted by `\newcounter`, then `\newcounter{something}` may very well have created a counter *macro* `\something`, which is problematic when you want to create a real macro `\something`.